# entering netrw commands (or ¿what is {cnt} in netrw help?)

Tags: vim, netrw

I'm puzzled with netrw. I want to go to a bookmark, and the help file says I can type {cnt}bm . I must be dumb, but I dont get it. :bm, {cnt}bm neither work. GVim on windows shows me a netrw menu in wich I can select 'Go to bookmark' and it works, but I want to use a keyboard shortcut. Ty for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem *very* confused indeed.

The command for jumping to a bookmark is `{cnt}gb` (not `{cnt}bm`) in which `{cnt}` is a bookmark number. In normal mode:

```
gb     " jump to latest bookmark
2gb    " jump to bookmark number 2
```

You can see a list of bookmarks and their numbers with `qb`.

Comment: Yes I am confused, sorry I mistaken the commands. So I only have currently one bookmark. If I type :gb I get "Not an editor command gb". I type now :e. to I get a netrw listing of my current path. I type :gb ->same error message. But I now see a 'Netrw' menu on gvim, so if I dropdown that menu to Bookmarks, I see my bookmark and can select it. But this being vim, I expect to do that with a keyboard command. How?

Comment: edit: sorry, yes I was confused. For anyone on the same confusion, this 'gb' are not commands (like entering :gb) but a netrw-own command. So the idea is to type just gb, without : on a netrw listing.

Comment: `gb` is a *normal mode* command (created by way of a mapping) while `:gb` would be (if it existed) an *Ex command*.